# Remove Duplicates in Xml Document

Tags: c#, xml, duplicates

I have two XML documents that contain a list of products. Currently, we just copy one and paste it into the other and create a new merged document, however, these two files have a number of the same products so I need to merge the two **and remove the duplicates**. My XML documents are in the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <table>
       <row Code="HST15154"
       ProductName="test"
       ProductName_EN=""
       Description_EN=""
       Price=""
       ProductType1="HST ACCESSORIES"
       ProductType2="SAM - Accessories"
       ProductCategory="Accessories"
       Remarks=""
       />
    </table>
```

I found some code that I tried to alter to my needs [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4c64446-3cd3-4f3f-bf33-f4da9ed0583c/deleting-the-duplicate-nodes-of-xml-file-using-c?forum=csharplanguage). I need only one of each "Code."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

namespace HST_Merging_Console_App
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //open the xml document
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("U:\\Documents (U)\\XML Merging Tool\\productcollection_us.xml");

            //select all row elements
            XmlNodeList parts = doc.SelectNodes("/row");

            //create a list of previously seen P/Ns
            List<string> PartsSeen = new List<string>();

            foreach(XmlNode part in parts)
            {
                string partNumber = part.Attributes["Code"].Value;

                //for each part, see if we have seen it before, if it is in the list,
                //remove the part element from the parent to which it belongs
                if (PartsSeen.Contains(partNumber))
                    part.ParentNode.RemoveChild(part);
                else
                    PartsSeen.Add(partNumber);
            }
            Console.Read();
            doc.Save("U:\\Documents (U)\\XML Merging Tool\\productcollection_merged.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm receiving a couple errors when I run this:

**CS1061** - 'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (Line 16)

**CS1503** - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' (Line 33)

Another approach I've considered is to take the first file and load into a dataset then take the second file and load it into a 2nd dataset. Then loop through the 2nd dataset searching for the Code in the 1st dataset, if found update the row, if not, add the row.

*This is my first time working with C# and trying to create a program to run on a server*. Any help and/or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of application is this? Can you use XDocument instead?

Comment: I would like to do it as a .net application. Also, I'm using Visual Studios 2015.

Comment: What do you determine as duplicate? Is everything the same, or do they all have unique codes for example so only need to match on that to be a duplicate?

Comment: If the Code is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LINQ to Xml`.
With `HashSet` you can recognize duplicate codes. `HashSet.Add()` will return false if same value already exists in the set.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(yourPath);
var codes = new HashSet<string>();

// .ToList() is important for removing elements
foreach(var row in doc.Root.Elements("row").ToList())
{
    var code = row.Attribute("Code").Value;
    var isUniqueCode = codes.Add(code);
    if(isUniqueCode == false)
    {
        row.Remove();
    }
}

doc.Save(newPath);
```

Comment: When I try this, I get " 'XDocument' does not exist in the current context" and if I try "XmlDocument," I get several errors, "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable" and "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'XmlDocument.Load(string)' "

Comment: Add `using System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: Is there another reference I need to make for the ToList()? That is showing up as not found now.

Comment: `System.Linq` :). Visual studio 2015 have good new feature which suggest  adding a `using` directives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which is a little easier to use that XmlDocument. When using that you will need to as `using System.Xml.Linq`. Then simply group on the "Code" attribute like this use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("U:\\Documents (U)\\XML Merging Tool\\productcollection_us.xml");

var uniqueProducts = doc.Root.Elements("row").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("Code"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in a more easy way, try something like this:

```
var uniques = doc.Descendants("row").Attributes("Code").Distinct()
```

i haven't tested this though so it might need some modifications